# Refactor class implementation file to use namespace

Tags: refactoring, clion

I have a class called `Point` that I put into a namespace as follows:

`namespace A::B {
    class Point { ....`

However, my implementation `.cpp` file is no longer using the correct scopes. Is there an easier and faster way to refactor than going to each individual function and adding the correct scope? For example, I know I have to go to the implementation file and do this to every function.

`A::B::Point::Point() {}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving classes to other namespaces is not possible, at the moment. See [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-1168).

But in your case, it seems to come down to a simple search-and-replace. Open the `cpp` file, then press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and insert the old and new namespace.
If this needs to be done to a bunch of files, you may want to use an external tool, like [sed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed).